# Builds failing after upgrading to Java7, Missing Tools.jar and bad class versions

Tags: java

I recently upgraded to Java7 on my Macbook Pro.  I downloaded the JDK (not the JRE).

```
» javac version
javac 1.7.0_17

» echo $JAVA_HOME    
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, when trying to run a build, one of the maven compiler plugins is failing, claiming I have a JRE installed:

```
» mvn install
[ERROR] execute error
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: You need to run build with JDK
 or have tools.jar on the classpath.
If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well
    at com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractProcessorMojo.java:263)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
```

I'm confused, as I clearly have a JDK installed.  My `MAVEN_OPTS` don't do anything funny:

```
» echo $MAVEN_OPTS          
-Xmx512m
```

Trying to debug, I checked the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.mysema.maven/maven-apt-plugin/1.0.4/com/mysema/maven/apt/AbstractProcessorMojo.java?av=f#261) of the plugin in question, which is doing the following:

```
    try {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if (compiler == null) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath."
                    + "If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well");
        }
```

That seems harmless, so I suspected something wrong on my command line env, and wrote a simple test:

```
// Main.java
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if (compiler == null)
        {
            System.out.print("Compiler is null");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Compiler is not null");
        }
    }

}

» javac Main.java

Main.java:1: cannot access javax.tools.JavaCompiler
bad class file: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(javax/tools/JavaCompiler.class)
class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
                   ^
1 error
```

If I understand that error correctly, it suggests a Java7 compiler running against a Java5 `rt.jar`?

I'm not sure what's going on here.

I clearly have a Java7 JDK installed, but don't understand:

- Why is the maven plugin is returning null for the compiler?
- Why am I getting class version errors?

### Update

Answers are suggesting a messed up JRE / JDK install.  I agree this seems likely, but having trouble tracking down where the culprit lies.

Some additional info:

```
» which javac
/usr/bin/javac

ls -ltra /usr/bin/javac
/usr/bin/javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac

cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
ls -ltra

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 18 Feb 08:39 A
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 18 Feb 08:39 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 14 Jun 11:14 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   58 14 Jun 11:15 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 14 Jun 11:15 .
```

So, the javac that is running is the one installed in `A/Commands`.   I'm not sure if this is correct or not.  It seems wrong from my windows days, but I'm not familiar enough with how Mac treats Java install to go tinkering.

My `$JAVA_HOME` points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home`, which has the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  wheel       340  5 Feb 08:10 jre
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel    123324  5 Feb 08:10 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  wheel       170  5 Feb 08:10 man
drwxrwxr-x   9 root  wheel       306  2 Mar 02:10 db
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel      3339  2 Mar 02:10 COPYRIGHT
drwxrwxr-x   9 root  wheel       306  2 Mar 02:10 include
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel  19997030  2 Mar 02:10 src.zip
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel       447  2 Mar 02:10 release
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel    172252  2 Mar 02:10 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel       114  2 Mar 02:10 README.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel        40  2 Mar 02:10 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  wheel       170  2 Mar 02:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x  15 root  wheel       510  2 Mar 02:13 .
drwxrwxr-x  13 root  wheel       442  2 Mar 02:13 lib
drwxrwxr-x  43 root  wheel      1462  2 Mar 02:13 bin
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a `tools.jar` sitting in `/Library/Java/Extensions`

I'm not sure if this is standard or not.

However, copying the `tools.jar` from the JDK7 `$JAVA_HOME/lib` to `/Library/Java/Extensions` solved all my problems.

I should also point out that in my original question I had updated the Java `CurrentSDK` to point to `JDK7`:

```
CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents
```

This was a Bad Idea, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151463/59015).

I updated this to point back to 1.6.  Although this seems counter-intuitive, it was required to get things working.

The current listing of `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` with a `1.7` JDK looks as follows:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 18 Feb 08:36 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 18 Feb 08:39 A
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 18 Feb 08:39 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 14 Jun 11:35 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 14 Jun 12:31 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 14 Jun 12:31 .
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to set JAVA_HOME on MacOS X is to use:

```
[user@ip ~]$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7)
[user@ip ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Your java installation is broken if, after doing this, $JAVA_HOME/lib does not contain a tools.jar.

Tip: I have these two aliases specified in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias java6="export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.6)"  
alias java7="export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7)"
```

Placing jars in /Library/Java/Extensions is equivalent to putting them in the global classpath and is rarely a good idea.

Comment: BTW: I somehow accidentally downvoted this instead of upvoting it, as it fixed it for me! If you care, edit your answer and it'll allow me to upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

Forget Maven.

What directory has the JDK `/bin` directory?  That's `JAVA_HOME`.

I suspect that you've set the environment variable incorrectly.

And that `/bin` ought to have all the executables for the JDK tools: javac, java, jar, javap, etc.

If that's not the case, then you don't have JDK, you've got JRE.

I've got a Windows machine.  Here's where I have JDK installed:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
```

And here's JAVA_HOME:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_02
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking perhaps an inconsistency between `$JAVA_HOME` and `which javac` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to answer your question.  The current JDK (as defined by `JAVA_HOME` contains the `/bin` directory.  However, `which javac` is running from some wierd mac-looking path, which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 2):

No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Maven build failure in eclipse with above error was fixed by un-installing older version of java.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably javac is running from JRE and not JDK. tools.jar is only available in JDK. Confirm the path of javac/java by using `which`

```
which javac
```

Drag correct Java7 version to top in Java Preferences (Launchapad/Others). That should point A to JDK7.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found the answer in another thread:

[Symbolic link messed up on OSX while trying to change the Java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845411/symbolic-link-messed-up-on-osx-while-trying-to-change-the-java-version?rq=1)

I set JAVA_HOME as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

and it's working now.

Comment: This works if you want to go back to the base Java install. If you're trying to use a different version of Java, this totally won't do you any good.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that the `tools.jar` in `/Library/Java/Extensions` is not from the right version of the JDK, then move it out of the way, so that there is no tools.jar there and there is a tools.jar in `$JAVA_HOME/lib` (as set in the previous response).

eg

```
cd 
sudo mv /Library/Java/Extensions/tools.jar tools.jar.safe
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the following error on a maven project: Failed to execute goal on project cobertura-maven-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.6: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project cobertura-maven-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.6: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar

I fixed it by creating a lib dir under /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents and adding tools.jar to it.

Full path would be this for tools.jar in this particular instance: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/lib/tools.jar