# Maven & JDK 1.7 on Mac

Tags: macos, maven-3, java, java-7

When I try to compile a project with Maven I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project webserverlog: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project webserverlog: Compilation failure
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

My JAVA_HOME is pointing to the JDK:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home

$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -version
javac 1.7.0_25
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I'm not sure why Maven adds '/jre' to the end of JAVA_HOME, but looking at some other posts this doesn't seem to be the problem:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 18:44:56+1000)
Maven home: /Users/jerry/dev/springsource/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I've searched for a solution to this problem and tried different things for the last couple of days, but can't find anything that works.  I've seen some threads with a similar problem, but none of the suggestions worked for me.

Does anyone know how to solve this?  Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: try to execute this in console: `/usr/libexec/java_home`, what does it return?

Comment: I get `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/CurrentJDK/Contents/Home`

Comment: does this ever exist `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/CurrentJDK/Contents/Home`? this is different from `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home`?

Comment: I have reinstalled OS X and it cleaned out all the previous versions of Java.  Now I only have the Oracle 1.7.0_25 version installed.  So, when I run `$ /usr/libexec/java_home` I get `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/CurrentJDK/Contents/Home`.  When I run `$ echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/CurrentJDK/Contents/Home`.  And when I run `$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -version` I get `javac 1.7.0_25
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>`.  Which is now all pointing to the same location.  But I still have the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is right, but when I run `$ which javac` I get `/usr/bin/javac`.  Where `/usr/bin/javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current -> A`.  Therefore, `/usr/bin/javac` points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac`.  In any case, Maven should be using JAVA_HOME, right?

Comment: It should be. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279586/java-home-in-maven, it seems java home in maven output is right. But checkout my mvn output: `Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_29, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_29-b11-402.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"` which is different from yours.

Comment: @TonyChen thanks for that link.  It makes sense.  I've looked at the problem bit more, and I think it relates to the maven compiler plugin.  When I specify the source and target versions as 1.7 Maven throws a different error `javac: invalid flag: -s`.  If I remove those I get the `Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?` error.  BTW, compiling my previous project with Maven worked fine on the 1.6 version, same as yours.  I'm just trying to run the Java EE 7 examples from Glassfish 4, so need the JDK 7 to work. I'll see whether it works on a Windows VM.

Comment: I finally got this working.  Found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099379/builds-failing-after-upgrading-to-java7-missing-tools-jar-and-bad-class-version.  Basically copying $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar to /Library/Java/Extensions fixed it.

Comment: Good to know that. You can post your answer below and accept that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 5):

You should assign the real path to the JDK to the JAVA_HOME variable instead of leaving the CurrentJDK literal. For some reason in Mac OS X the CurrentJDK is not pointing to the actual one regarding Maven.  Try something like this in your .profile but replacing you actual jdk folder name:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: You can use `export JAVA_HOME="$( /usr/libexec/java_home )"` to avoid having to update this every time you install a new minor version.

Comment: This helped me get around my issue. If other n00bs like me encounter the issue, you need to edit the .profile or .bash_profile file located in your home folder (e.g. `nano ~/.profile`), and add the `export` line in @IanRoberts's comment on its own new line, then press ctrl+x to save and exit the file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, one cause  of "no source files" is lack of disk space wherever tmp points.

Looks like maven and javac store some items in TEMP/TMP/TMDIR and if that director doesn't exist, lacks space, lacks permissions then you can see that problem.  at least we did on windows and I suspect it'll happen on better operating systems too.