# Spring ROO build error: no tools.jar , jdk7, pom.xml

Tags: spring, roo, tools.jar

every pioneers,

I want to try to build Spring Roo 2.0.0.M2(http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) with its saying of STS 3.7.0 and JDK 1.7.0_45, and I couldn't find the solution even according the post on other sites or on  " [Builds failing after upgrading to Java7, Missing Tools.jar and bad class versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099379/builds-failing-after-upgrading-to-java7-missing-tools-jar-and-bad-class-version) " .

The error messages on auto generated POM.xml are: 
??????????????????????????????????????
You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you 
 run eclipse under JDK as well (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources) 
 org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the 
 classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well at 
 com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractProcessorMojo.java:362) at 
....
?????????????????????????????????????

Even I have tried: add JDK1.7.0_45 path but not JRE path in STS project, and even I added tools.jar directly in project build-paths, and even I use "mvn generate source" and add the generate jar into source path. The error about apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3  is still there.

Is there any person who can help? I will try to use old apt-maven-plugin latter.

Comment: I may have found the answer: because now ROO's command of project setup will default use JDK 1.8, so when I follow steps on http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/ , you have to add --java 7 to it, but after I follow the step of "repository jpa --all --package ~.repository
"  , there suddenly an error appears: "you must specify interface for the command" .

Comment: My new question for Spring ROO's leaders:
1st, is ROO feasible for setting up a Spring+Strutes+Hibernate project?
2nd, what kind of applications ROO can auto program for us?
3rd, SS+mybatis is also a good enterprise-level Java BS platform, why roo's JPA doesn't support 
for mybatis?